# Is there an way to group rows of data by a percentage window of a value within the given dataset, and then iterate through the dataset?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a large csv file from some association rule mining. Two of the columns are rules and confidence score.

The rules column contains lists of items of varying length e.g.

```
[[Dog],[Dog,Cat],[Dog,Cat,Hamster],[Dog,Cat,Hamster,Goldfish]]
```

The confidence score column contains a list of numbers between 0 and 1 e.g.

```
[0.1, 0.5, 0.1, 0.5]
```

I want to remove redundant rows based on whether the rule value is a subset of the other rule values, but I only want to remove rows with similar confidence scores (within a confidence window, say 5%).

In the above example the rows that would remain are [Dog] and [Dog,Cat].

`[Dog`] would remain because `[Dog]` and `[Dog,Cat,Hamster]` would be grouped together because of their confidence score of 0.1, then `[Dog,Cat,Hamster]` would then be removed because `[Dog]` is a subset of `[Dog,Cat,Hamster]` and hence the rule `[Dog,Cat,Hamster]` is redundant.

Similarly, `[Dog,Cat]` and `[Dog,Cat,Hamster,Goldfish]` both have a confidence score of 0.5, and `[Dog,Cat,Hamster,Goldfish]` would be removed because [Dog,Cat] is a subset of [Dog,Cat,Hamster,Goldfish].

I know the first thing I need to do is look at the confidence score of the smallest rule, group together all the rules that fall within the confidence window of that score, and then remove all the rules that are a superset of the smaller rule. Then I need to move onto the next smallest rule and do the same, until all rules have been reduced/stemmed.

I'm wondering is there an easy way to do this in Python/Pandas?

I'm quite new to coding so I don't know if this is possible at all.

Thanks

Comment: Is it safe to assume that each rules list has distinct values? E.g. is it correct to say that a rule couldn't contain two of the same value, such as ['Dog','Dog']? If so, might be worth converting the rules from lists to sets, so that we can use the set.issubset() function to check if a rule is a subset of another rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort the pair values from the two columns by both confidence value AND length of the rules. Then we will have the lowest conf score first, and within rules with the same conf scores, the shortest list will appear first. We iterate through this sorted rule/conf pairs with the "two finger" approach. The first finger is the current rule/conf pair. The second finger moves until we find the first rule that is either an unequal conf score (e.g. 0.5 if our first finger is on 0.1) OR if the rule is not a subset (e.g. ['Hamster'] encountered if our first finger is on ['Dog']). When we find such rule/conf pair, we append the rule/conf pair of our first finger, and advance our first finger to the pair we just processed. We continue the iteration, skipping pairs that fall under our criteria to remove, and appending and advancing when we find pairs that do not meet the "remove" criteria. Hope this makes sense.

```
rules = [['Dog'],['Dog','Cat'],['Dog','Cat','Hamster','Goldfish'], ['Dog','Cat','Hamster']]
confs = [0.1, 0.5, 0.1, 0.5]

# sort by conf values and size of rules to put the shortest sub-rule in the front
ruleConfPairs = sorted(zip(rules, confs), key=lambda x: (x[1], len(x[0])))

# initialize iteration
new_rules = []
new_confs = []
current_rule = ruleConfPairs[0][0]
current_conf = ruleConfPairs[0][1]

for rule, conf in ruleConfPairs[1:]:
    if current_conf == conf and set(current_rule).issubset(rule):
        # skip (i.e. remove) pair if it has the same confidence value AND rule is a subset
        continue
    # append current rule/conf pair if either confidence score is not equal OR rule is not a subset
    new_rules.append(current_rule)
    new_confs.append(current_conf)
    # advance our pair
    current_rule = rule
    current_conf = conf

# make sure to append the last pair
new_rules.append(current_rule)
new_confs.append(current_conf)

print(new_rules)
print(new_confs)
```

Output:

```
[['Dog'], ['Dog', 'Cat']]
[0.1, 0.5]
```